# Compatibility of Loopback 3 packages with Loopback4

Tags: npm, loopback, loopback4

I'm using `Loopback 3` and planning to start using `loopback 4`. They says that it has brand new `IoC core` built with *TypeScripts* (great !!). But that leaves some problems.

1. Is it has any performance/security advantage of TS over JS?
2. More importantly, can we use previously used LB3 packages with LB4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can we use previously used LB3 packages with LB4?

Unfortunately, most LB3 packages will not work with LB4. The version 4 uses a completely different design & programming model that is not backward compatible with LoopBack 3.

See [Understanding the differences between LoopBack 3 and LoopBack 4](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Understanding-the-differences.html).